# Como consigo contar o número de records em MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Eu tenho este código MySQL:

```
SELECT
    COUNT( PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO ) 
FROM
    PEDIDO
    JOIN PEDIDO P2 ON P2.COD_CLIENTE = PEDIDO.COD_CLIENTE 
    AND DATE( PEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO ) = DATE( P2.DT_PEDIDO ) 
    AND PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO <> P2.COD_PEDIDO
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENTE ON PEDIDO.COD_CLIENTE = CLIENTE.COD_CLIENTE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ESTADO ON CLIENTE.COD_ESTADO = ESTADO.COD_ESTADO
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CIDADE ON CLIENTE.COD_CIDADE = CIDADE.COD_CIDADE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN NOTA_FISCAL ON PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO = NOTA_FISCAL.COD_PEDIDO 
    AND NOTA_FISCAL.FG_EXCLUIDO = 'N'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OP_PEDIDO ON PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO = OP_PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO 
    AND OP_PEDIDO.NR_ORDEM > 0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TRANSPORTADOR ON TRANSPORTADOR.COD_TRANSPORTADOR = OP_PEDIDO.COD_TRANSPORTADORA
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PEDIDO_DEGUSTACAO ON PEDIDO_DEGUSTACAO.COD_PEDIDO = PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO 
WHERE
    PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO > 0 
    AND PEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO >= '2021-03-08' 
    AND PEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO <= '2021-03-09' 
GROUP BY
    PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO
```

O resultado deste select é :

```
COUNT(PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO)
1
1
1
1
1
3
3
3
3
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Queria saber como eu posso contar o número de records usando este código, por exemplo, é exibido 24 linhas nesse select, queria poder exibir este número, 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você remover o agrupamento da consulta, ou seja, **tirar esse trecho do código**.

```
GROUP BY
    PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO
```

Indico que você dê uma estudada em como funciona o [`GROUP BY`](http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/mysql-group-by-agrupamento-de-registros-26/).

---

De acordo com comentário aqui na resposta, você precisa então usar o [`distinct`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php) na consulta, assim cada ocorrência do código só será contabilizada uma vez:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(PEDIDO.COD_PEDIDO))
```

Comment: Se você reparar, nos registros, tem alguns que sinalizam "3" eu preciso sinalizar o número de linhas, não a soma, que é o que ocorre ao remover o `GROUP BY`

Comment: @MiguelKrug, veja se responde